# USB not showing vendor Information

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, filesystems, usb-flash-drive

I bought a new "Sony 32GB USM32X USB 3.0" Pen Drive today. I have tried to collect its vendor and model information through the command line(I am a Linux user). The sony Pen drive shows product name as "UDisk" and vendor as "General", so I am really confused with its authenticity. I do not have another Sony pen drive with me to check it.

```
    sonyvaio ~ # lsblk --output NAME,VENDOR,HCTL,PKNAME,ROTA,MODEL,SERIAL
    NAME   VENDOR   HCTL       PKNAME ROTA MODEL            SERIAL
    sda    ATA      0:0:0:0              1 Hitachi HTS54505 121106TE85313Q1J5Z9R
    ├─sda2                     sda       1                  
    ├─sda3                     sda       1                  
    ├─sda4                     sda       1                  
    ├─sda5                     sda       1                  
    ├─sda6                     sda       1                  
    ├─sda7                     sda       1                  
    ├─sda8                     sda       1                  
    └─sda9                     sda       1                  
    sdb    General  9:0:0:0              1 UDisk            
    └─sdb1                     sdb       1                  
    sdc    SanDisk  11:0:0:0             1 Cruzer Micro     07753013C70362CF
    └─sdc1                     sdc       1                  
    sdd    SanDisk  12:0:0:0             1 Cruzer Blade     20060266001B3FB224DB
    ├─sdd1                     sdd       1                  
    ├─sdd2                     sdd       1                  
    └─sdd3                     sdd       1                  
    sr0    MATSHITA 4:0:0:0              1 DVD-RAM UJ880AS  UF83_878074

  *-usb:3
       description: Mass storage device
       product: UDisk [48D:1234]
       vendor: General [48D]
       physical id: 4
       bus info: usb@3:4
       logical name: scsi9
       version: 1.00
       capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi emulated scsi-host
       configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=100mA speed=480Mbit/s
     *-disk
          description: SCSI Disk
          physical id: 0.0.0
          bus info: scsi@9:0.0.0
          logical name: /dev/sdb
          size: 30GiB (32GB)
          capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
          configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=434e1a59
```

In the above result, /dev/sdb is the new Sony 32GB pen drive. As you can see, rest HDD and USB's show their Product and Vendor name correctly but not Sony.

Do you know if this is normal or if it's a duplicate product made in the name of Sony?. I bought it through a popular online purchase website.

[Pic of all 3 pen drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK3OR.jpg)

Comment: What's the output of *lsusb*? And of *udevadm info -q all -n /dev/sdb*?

Comment: It's the same.
`E: ID_TYPE=disk
E: ID_VENDOR=General
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=General\x20
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=048d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's the same. E: ID_TYPE=disk E: ID_VENDOR=General E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=General\x20 E: ID_VENDOR_ID=048d –

No, it is not: now we see the all-important *Vendor ID*, which in your case is **048D**. It was missing from your previous info (the word *General* is not informative, AFAIK). A [Google Search](http://usbspeed.nirsoft.net/?o=1&vname=Integrated%20Technology%20Express%2C%20Inc.&vid=1165&pid=4466) shows that this Vendor ID belongs to one [Integrated Technology Express](http://www.ite.com.tw/), a chinese manufacturer which, judging from another Google search, is **in no way** related to Sony. You have been *scammed*.

I would like to suggest to you to double check your USB device because, as related [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Dont-fall-for-the-Flash-Drive-Scam!/),

> I recently became aware of a major scam on eBay. Hackers in China are selling flash drives with less memory than they advertise. Users like PikesPeakTraders sell thousands of 'hacked' flash drives from China. The problem is that the hackers change a log file that makes the flash drive think it has more memory than it does. When you receive the drive, if you right click and go to properties it will display a larger amount of memory than it really has- so when you put data on it that exceeds it's actual memory, old data will be deleted.

The problem for you is not so much *eBay*, of course, but the fact that hacked USB devices are freely circulating on the market, and your fake-Sony device is a prime candidate for containing less memory than advertised. You can find similar articles [here](https://flashchiptech.wordpress.com/2009/10/06/how-can-you-spot-fake-flash-memory-chips-what-is-the-key-factor-that-determines-if-mp3-mp4-players-usb-flash-drives-or-memory-cards-are-fake-capacity/), [here](http://sushifury.com/2010/03/i-got-sold-a-fake-usb-flash-drive-on-ebay-heres-how-i-fixed-my-situation-and-how-you-can-avoid-this-situation-yourself/), or even [on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaHokQ5EWv0). I am sure there are many, many more.

Comment: Absolutely right. I got cheated by them. They sent me a duplicate product in the name of super brand Sony :(

Answer (score 0):

I have bought Sony USB too, and it's not showing vendor information as well. It just shows UDisk. I have some more (Kingston, Lexar) usb's which show UDisk too. One Lexar (that's supposedly 64Gb but really 8Gb) only shows Udisk and nothing more. I'm sure your one is a rip-off as well, so make sure to test it with h2testw. If it's 32Gb, there's not much to worry, only write times, and it shouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: Yeah, that is the truth I think. Anyways size showing 32GB itself while testing, also no issues with write/read. so I feel comfort now :)